# CSS 3 Filter W/ Background-clip

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, gradient

I have this CSS. the property FILTER In class .crumb make my background and this works perfectly and Chrome, Firefox, safari, iPad, iPhone,Android... but for an unknown reason. It just doesnt work on ie9. I see the dark bordes with a radius, but the background is just completly square.

```
.left-crumb {
margin-left:15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}

.crumb {
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
background-image:0 color-stop(0.3,#798aad), color-stop(0.51,#6276a0), color-stop(0.51,#556a97), color-stop(0.75,#566c98), to(#546993));
background:linear-gradient(top,#4c4c4c0%,#59595912%,#66666625%,#47474739%,#2c2c2c50%,#00000051%,#11111160%,#2b2b2b76%,#1c1c1c91%,#131313100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4c4c4c',endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0);
font-weight:bolder;
border:solid 1px #54617D;
height:30px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
display:inline-block;
color:#FFF;
line-height:28px;
border-color:#484E59 #aaa #4C5C7A #54617D;
}

.right-crumb {
position:relative;
margin-right:10px;
padding-right:25px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
}
```

Here's a quick HTML so you can test.

```
<div id="adminPanel"><a class="left-crumb crumb right-crumb" href="admin.php">Admin panel</a></div>
```

## adminPanel is just a div to contain all

Comment: IE filters (which are not part of CSS3 at all) are not backgrounds, so they'll never be affected by background or border clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still IE9 doesn't supports yet, but you can use SVG to achieve this, please download the source code and check the demo here

http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/